# React pose - animate in from right, exit on left

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-pose

I am currently playing around with React pose. What I'm trying to do is animate different boxes in from the right, and exit them on the left. However, I can't seem to get the `preEnterPose` to work the way I want it. It always seems to default to the exit pose.

How can I get the boxes to animate in from the right, and exit on the left? Here is what I am working with
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-pose-enterexit-o2qqi?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import posed, { PoseGroup } from "react-pose";
import "./styles.css";

const Card = posed.div({
  enter: {
    x: 0,
    opacity: 1,
    preEnterPose: {
      x: 50
    },
    delay: 300,
    transition: {
      x: { type: "spring", stiffness: 1000, damping: 15 },
      default: { duration: 300 }
    }
  },
  exit: {
    x: -50,
    opacity: 0,
    transition: { duration: 150 }
  }
});

class Example extends React.Component {
  state = { isVisible: false, index: 0, items: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"] };

  componentDidMount() {}

  next = () => {
    if (this.state.index === this.state.items.length - 1) {
      this.setState({
        index: 0
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        index: this.state.index + 1
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { index, items } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <PoseGroup>
          {items.map((id, idx) => {
            if (idx === index) {
              return (
                <Card className="card" key={idx}>
                  {id}
                </Card>
              );
            }
            return null;
          })}
        </PoseGroup>
        <button onClick={this.next}>next</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you update your `posed.div` as the following.

```
const Card = posed.div({
  preEnterPose: {
    x: 50,
    opacity: 0,
    transition: { duration: 150 }
  },
  enter: {
    x: 0,
    opacity: 1,
    delay: 300,
    transition: {
      x: { type: "spring", stiffness: 1000, damping: 15 },
      default: { duration: 300 }
    }
  },
  exit: {
    x: -50,
    opacity: 0,
    transition: { duration: 150 }
  }
});
```

Then you set your `<PoseGroup>`'s `preEnterPose` props to your key of the pose `preEnterPose`. And it should work. `preEnterPose`'s default props is set to `exit`. Read it [here](https://popmotion.io/pose/api/posegroup/)

```
<PoseGroup preEnterPose="preEnterPose">
  {items.map((id, idx) => {
    if (idx === index) {
      return (
        <Card className="card" key={idx}>
          {id}
        </Card>
      );
    }
    return null;
  })}
</PoseGroup>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. This accomplishes what I wanted. Out of curiosity, is there a way to simultaneously play the "enter" pose of the next card while the "exit" pose is playing out on the current card?

Comment: Changing your `delay` in your `enter` pose key from `300` to `100` should give you the illusion of playing both animation simultaneously. Care to mark my answer as accepted answer ? :) @prawn